# Queries error sorting documents with find Pouchdb

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I wish to order/sort results with pouchdb.
I have created an index on the field i wish to sort by greater than 882

I've checked that the database exist

Then the result is like :

883

895

9

909

917

93

I am refering to the documentation : https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html
and this documentation : http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html

```
    this.db= new PouchDB('parcelles', {adapter: 'idb'});

        // Create an index to the field id_culture

            this.db.createIndex({
             index: {
             fields: ['id_culture']
              }
              }).then((result)=> {
                      console.log(result);

              }).catch(function (err) {

              });

        // Query with the sort filter

              this.db.find({
              selector: {
              id_culture: {$gte: '882'}
               },
              sort: ['id_culture']
               }).then( (result)=> {console.log(result);

               }).catch(function (err) {console.log(err);

               });
```

Comment: Those fields are sorted correctly, they are just sorted by textual representation, rather than numeric value. To sort by numeric value, the simplest option is to pad your numbers with leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute `id_culture` is a text string not a number. You will have to decide on a maximum possible size, for example 100,000,000 and left pad all your ids.

I recommend prefixes as well, so you could try, for example: Culture_00000009, Culture_00000909, Culture_00000093, etc. With ids like that sorting will work....

```
id_culture: {$gte: 'Culture_00000882'}
```

... giving ...

```
Culture_00000883
Culture_00000895
Culture_00000909
Culture_00000917
Culture_00001093
```